# MySQL Merge Two tables

Tags: mysql

How can I merge two tables into one table with a query?

I currently have tablea such that it has two columns Zone and Number
Then I have another table called Zones and this has Zone, Latitude, Longitude.

I want to end up with tablec containing Zone, Number, Latitude, Longitude.

But I don't know if I can do this with just a query. Normally I would run a PHP script query with a JOIN statement.

Comment: And a `join` should work in this case as well.

Comment: But that will not create a new table?

Comment: Put `create table <tablename> as` before the query.

Comment: A new table probably would not be normalized and thus may not be the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new "table" and don't mind not being able to insert data you could create a view, something like

```
CREATE VIEW tablec AS
  SELECT
      A.Zone,
      A.Number,
      B.Latitude,
      B.Longitude
  FROM tablea AS A
  INNER JOIN tableb AS B
  ON A.Zone = B.Zone`
```

Or you could create the table, but this would lose your references(so if you update tablea or tableb they could get out of sync):

```
CREATE TABLE tablec
  SELECT
      A.Zone,
      A.Number,
      B.Latitude,
      B.Longitude
  FROM tablea AS A
  INNER JOIN tableb AS B
  ON A.Zone = B.Zone`
```